# Powershell file-rename 20130702 into 2013-07-02

Tags: powershell, file-rename

I've got these pdf's

```
20130701_foo.pdf
20130702_foo.pdf
20130703_foo.pdf
```

And I want to rename it to

```
2013-07-01.pdf
2013-07-02.pdf
2013-07-03.pdf
```

For removing the _foo I've got:

```
Get-ChildItem *foo.pdf | foreach{Rename-Item $_ $_.Name.Replace("_foo","")}
```

How do I change `20130701.pdf` to `2013-07-01.pdf`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Insert method to add dashes at specific locations and remove _foo:

```
Get-ChildItem *_foo.pdf | 
Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Insert(4,'-').Insert(7,'-') -replace '_foo' }
```